# Обход триггера при вызове update

Tags: sql, postgresql, триггер

Есть триггер:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION LogTransfer_trigger_update_func() RETURNS trigger AS $TRIGGER$
DECLARE
    rec ComprositiontTransfer;
    sqlUpdate varchar;
BEGIN 
        if OLD."OldState_id" = 3 and OLD."NewState_id" = 5 then
            /* если этот код то еще и обновить лог транспортировки со статусом 3 надо */
            /* UPDATE "LogTransfer" SET  "Сomposition"=NEW."Сomposition" WHERE "Transfer_ID"=OLD."Transfer_ID" AND "OldState_id"=1 AND "NewState_id"=3; */
            sqlUpdate = 'UPDATE "' || OLD."SkladPostav" || '" SET "Count" = ("Count" - $2), "Changed" = true WHERE ("Name" = $1)';
            FOR rec.Name, rec.Count IN SELECT u.Name, u.Count FROM  unnest(OLD."Сomposition") u GROUP BY u.Name, u.Count
                LOOP
                    execute sqlUpdate using rec.Name, rec.Count;
                END LOOP;
            /* Добавляем по новой */
            sqlUpdate = 'UPDATE "' || OLD."SkladPostav" || '" SET "Count" = ("Count" + $2), "Changed" = true WHERE ("Name" = $1)';
            FOR rec.Name, rec.Count IN SELECT u.Name, u.Count FROM  unnest(NEW."Сomposition") u  GROUP BY u.Name, u.Count
                LOOP    
                    execute sqlUpdate using rec.Name, rec.Count;
            END LOOP;
        elsif OLD."OldState_id" = 1 and OLD."NewState_id" = 3 then 
            /* если этот код то еще и обновить лог транспортировки со статусом 3 надо */
            /*UPDATE "LogTransfer" SET  "Сomposition"=NEW."Сomposition" WHERE "Transfer_ID"=OLD."Transfer_ID" AND "OldState_id"=3 AND "NewState_id"=5;*/
            sqlUpdate = 'UPDATE "' || OLD."SkladPostav" || '" SET "Count" = ("Count" - $2), "Changed" = true WHERE ("Name" = $1)';
            FOR rec.Name, rec.Count IN SELECT u.Name, u.Count FROM  unnest(OLD."Сomposition") u GROUP BY u.Name, u.Count
                LOOP
                    execute sqlUpdate using rec.Name, rec.Count;
                END LOOP;
            /* Добавляем по новой */
            sqlUpdate = 'UPDATE "' || OLD."SkladPostav" || '" SET "Count" = ("Count" + $2), "Changed" = true WHERE ("Name" = $1)';
            FOR rec.Name, rec.Count IN SELECT u.Name, u.Count FROM  unnest(NEW."Сomposition") u  GROUP BY u.Name, u.Count
                LOOP    
                    execute sqlUpdate using rec.Name, rec.Count;
            END LOOP;
        end if;
    return NEW;
END;
$TRIGGER$
LANGUAGE  plpgsql;

CREATE TRIGGER LogTransfer_Update_trigger
AFTER UPDATE  ON "LogTransfer" FOR EACH ROW 
EXECUTE PROCEDURE LogTransfer_trigger_update_func();
```

Дак вот мне надо синхронно обновить две записи в таблице. Т.е. если обновляется со статусом 3->5 то так же надо обновить 1->3 и наоборот. Если я раскоменчу строки обновления в триггере. Он пишет что: переполнен максимальный стек глубины. Если в логике приложения вызываю два раза update то он мне делает все в двойном размере, так как срабатывает дважды. 
Вопрос:
Можно ли вызвать UPDATE в обход триггера в приложении, или как то корректно изменить данный триггер?

Comment: Ну вскидку - только добавить в таблицу еще одно поле, которое клиентское приложение трогать вообще не будет, а триггер, делая "второй" update будет его изменять (скажем делать +1 или a=1-a) и триггер что бы проверял - если это поле меняется - значит обновление идет из триггера и делать update не следует, что бы не зациклится.

Comment: Кстати, а зачем вы делаете запросы к logtransfer в виде строк и потом это выполняете, да еще и в цикле. Одним запросом и без execute покрасивее смотрелось бы.

Comment: Можете привести пример? Еще я нашел такие функции как: DISABLE TRIGGER; но при применении их в приложении, бд зависает

Comment: Пример: делаем поле с именем A default 1 (что бы null не оказалось). и пишите в триггере буквально `update LogTransfer set A=1-A where "OldState_id"=3 AND "NewState_id"=5 and OLD.A=NEW.A`

Comment: я говорю про цикл =)

Comment: А, я только сейчас заметил что у вас имя таблицы с количеством берется из записи ... ну да, с такой структурой БД по другому не выйдет. стоило бы хранить эти количества в одной таблице (или не хранить вовсе, если это не для оптимизации сделано)

Comment: Это сделано что бы работало =) Спасибо вам за отклик!

Comment: А disable trigger использовать, конечно, нельзя. Он работает вне транзакций и глобально. Так что передача признака, что обновление идет из триггера думаю единственный путь. Если создавать поле не подходит, можно отдельную таблицу сделать, в которую триггер перед началом обновления пишет id записей которые пытается менять, а при втором входе в триггер менять только в том случае если id нет в этой табличке и удалять записи из нее. Кстати, а postgress вообще позволяет в триггерах for each row менять ту таблицу на которую он написан ? большинство других СУБД такого не позволяют в принципе